# same user two login - chat username on site x shows SO user name

Tags: support, chat

I was using multiple SO sites,like many others, under my one email address. Later I decided to break one my account on one SO site (lets call it X.SE) because I did not want to have public profile on that account. The SO staff helped me create a separate account, with some restrictions, that is

- I must not login using my old email address. If I do my account may automatically get merged again.
- I will lose some of my important gadgets that I worked hard for.

Now I understand this feature is not fully supported and I am fine with. But the problem I am facing now is when I chat on this site X.SE, my SO username is shown instead of my X.SE user name. Can this be fixed at least so I can stand independent on that site and get invoved in healthy discussions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chat is automatically associated with the account with the highest reputation.

You can reassign the site in your chat profile.

[image: Example]

Comment: OK, this is helpful but the problem I faced here is when I go to site X.SE chat profile, it allows me to change nick to my other SE site,but not site x.SE. Other than that, the answer is very helpful.

Comment: @Dave do you have more than 20 reputation on the target site?

Comment: @Dave: Which site do you want? I'll try using my mod powers to change it for you. Is it [skeptics.se]?

Comment: @Dave: Oh, it's an entirely different user? You can't associate this user with another user in chat.

Comment: Come to chat by that user. I'll help you from there descretely. You can delete the private comments.

Comment: @MadarUchiha Thank you a lot for your help!