# My comment was moved to a chat room, and it is not attributed to my site-specific username

Tags: support, comments, chat, display-names, move-to-chat

On one of the StackExchange sites, I have changed my display name from pacoverflow to something else.

Recently there was a question on that site in which a lot of people left comments, including me. I just noticed that all of the comments on that question were moved to chat. So I went into the chat room, and the comment that I left actually has "pacoverflow" next to it, not my site-specific username. This seems like a bug.

Comment: i assume this is due to the two sites sharing the same chat server. In that situation, which site would chat pull a username from? (surely this is answered somewhere)

Comment: @KevinB Perhaps it pulls from the network profile which you can see here: https://stackexchange.com/users/current

Comment: Incidentally I updated my display name for all sites recently, but I just now noticed that my own network profile still has my old name (Kodos Johnson). See: https://stackexchange.com/users/2940117/kodos-johnson

Comment: For some chat servers maybe? for me my network profile until today was incorrect but chat was still showing the correct profile from MSE and SO; my understanding is that there's 3 chat servers, MSE, SO, then the rest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [same user two login - chat username on site x shows SO user name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175018/282094), or   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295313/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63997/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279204/282094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug - it's due to how Chat works.

Chat profiles are per server, not per site, and all sites other than Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange share a single server. Your [chat.SE profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/126571/pacoverflow) has its parent site set to English Language & Usage, so your username in chat matches your username on EL&U.

You can reparent your chat account to another site, but that will change your username in chat everywhere on that chat server (other than in chat history). There's no way to have your username appear different per site other than on Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow, which have their own chat servers.